# ListPicker SelectionChanged gets called multiple times

Tags: c#, xaml, events, windows-phone-8

the ListPicker is a Control from the [WP8 Toolkit.](http://phone.codeplex.com/)

**Code:**

```
private void field_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure we don't handle the event during initiation.
    if (e.RemovedItems != null && e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        if (this.field.SelectedItems != null)
        {
            if (this.field.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                ListPicker_SelectionChanged(sender, e);
                //Make needed proffesions visable:
                profls.Clear();
                foreach (ListPickItem item in field.SelectedItems)
                    switch (item.Tag)
                    {
                        default:
                            foreach (ListPickItem iitem in profl[9])
                                profls.Add(iitem);
                            break;
                        case 90017:
                            foreach (ListPickItem iitem in profl[0])
                                profls.Add(iitem);
                            break;
                        case 9000:
                            foreach (ListPickItem iitem in profl[1])
                                profls.Add(iitem);
                            break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Please notice that a `profession` ListPicker's ItemsSource is Data Binded to the `profls` var.
- I modified the Listpicker so that I can also set the SelectedItems property and not only read from it (following [this](http://community.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2012/02/02/how-to-databind-selecteditems-of-the-listpicker-and-recurringdayspicker.aspx) guide) and it works great.

**Problem:**

The `field_SelectionChanged` event gets called multiple times whenever I change the `field` listpicker's selecteditems. (i want it to be called only once..) Another wierd thing is that on one of the last calls the `field_SelectedItems` is equal to the old selectedItems (the ones before the "change")..

**Is it a bug or my problem? (How do I fix it?)**

---

**EDIT:**

I checked and it appears that it gets called only once if the are no selected items in the listpicker before I select items. (I mean that SelectedItems is empty before I select new items)

Comment: Can you show the code where you subscribe to the `SelectionChanged` event?

Comment: @MatthewWatson It's in the XAML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed :)

I used the code suggested in this answer: [listPicker not updating selection in full mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559224/listpicker-not-updating-selection-in-full-mode)

```
if (MyListPicker.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
 //Code..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue of the selectedchange event being called twice.At the end of the listPicker_selectedchange event, set the listpicker selected index to -1.

```
private void listpicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  //Code
  listpicker.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Thank you Dan Barzilay!!